# Array of dropdown menus with dependencies using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a dynamic form in HTML/Jquery with the intention of allowing the user to dynamically build a query (which will be used to write an SQL statement). 
Note: The form will be posted to a PHP page which will generate the MySQL.

The requirements are:

- The user can add as many rows as they like using the + and - buttons, each row should contain 2 dropdowns and a text box.
- The second dropdown on each row should display a list which is relative to the option selected in the first drop down on that row. I have got this working for a single line (As can be seen in the attached JSFiddle) but not for multiple lines.
- Also, If the option selected in the first dropdown is 'Date' (or similar), then the text box (3rd item on the row) should change to a different class in order to display a datepicker when clicked on (I already have the code for the datepicker, but don't know how to change the class of the field)

I have to admit I'm not too hot on Jquery, but using bits from some other examples on this site I've been able to come up with the following example.

You'll see that when picking one of the top 2 items in the first drop down menu, you'll get the values in the second drop down menu to change, however, this only works on the top line. As soon as you add another line, the dependency for previous lines is lost.

The code I'm using for the dropdown dependency is:

```
$("#company").change(function() {
    $('select[name="product"]').removeAttr("name").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().attr("name", "product");
});
```

I realise the code is a mess as I've cobbled together bits from multiple examples. Any suggestions/feedback welcome :)

[Please click here for JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkPsJ/)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what your question is.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. I need the values in the second dropdown menu to be dependent on the value selected in the first dropdown menu. Please see the JsFiddle link at the bottom of my query for the full code sample.

Comment: Well you could create a map : first-column-value => [ second-column-value0, second-column-value0, ... ]. And use this map, when cloning your lines, to update the select input with the values corresponding to the value of the first select. You can use objects to create a map in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry. Are you able to provide a code sample that I can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with dynamically-created elements it's a better idea to go with classes and not id attributes for your jQUery selectors. Change your markup to something like:

```
<select id='company' name='company' class="company">
```

and ...

```
<select id='Title' name='product' class="Title">
```

and then you can use:

```
function () {
    var self = $(this),
        val = self.val(),
        ddl = self.siblings('select.' + val);
    self.siblings('select').removeAttr("name").hide();
    ddl.show().attr("name", "product");
}
```

as your handler. You'll also [probably] want to use event delegation to ensure that the handler runs on the elements that are created after the handler is bound:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select.company', function () {
     var self = $(this),
         val = self.val(),
         ddl = self.siblings('select.' + val);
     self.siblings('select').removeAttr("name").hide();
     ddl.show().attr("name", "product");
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QkPsJ/1/

**UPDATE**

Sorry I missed that part of the question. To add a `datepicker` class, just add this to the handler:

```
if (val === "DateCreated") {
    self.siblings('input.next').addClass('ui-datepicker');
    //init datepicker
} else {
    //destroy datepicker
    self.siblings('input.next').removeClass('ui-datepicker');
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkPsJ/2/

Comment: This is brilliant pete. It does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: There was one other query. I need the class of the textbox to change if the user chooses 'Date Created' in the first dropdown menu. Are you able to help with this?